# Search table for string in column name and return list of values for that column Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have the table below. I want to use the string of the column name, "column_n", to search the table for the values in that column (code needs to be the same for any string column name). The code needs to return a list of all the values from that column (in the same order as they appear in the column).

I tried doing this in Anylogic but the software requires to write the name of the column in the code (i.e. `selectFrom(db).list(db.column_1)` ). Need to be able to do this dynamically for any column name.

| activity_id | column_1 | column_2 | ... | column_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| activity1 | 1 | 2 |  | 3 |
| activity2 | 0 | 1 |  | 1 |
| activity3 | 4 | 0 |  | 0 |
| activity4 | 1 | 2 |  | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SQL form of AnyLogic database queries instead of the QueryDSL style you're using here; then you can easily just 'assemble' the required column name into the SQL string. For example

```
List<Integer> intColValues = selectValues("SELECT " + colName + " FROM table_1;");
```

where, for example, `colName` is the (`String`) argument to a function including the code above.

Comment: This worked! Many thanks for this straightforward answer. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a reference to a database table in a variable by using the following type:

`com.mysema.query.sql.RelationalPathBase`

When selecting values of double (int, String, etc.) type in a particular column, you may get the column by index calling `variable.getColumns().get(index)`. Then you need to cast it to the corresponding type like below:

```
List<Double> resultRows =  selectFrom(variable).where( ( (com.mysema.query.types.path.NumberPath<Double>) variable.getColumns().get(1) ).eq(2.0)) .list(( (com.mysema.query.types.path.NumberPath<Double>) variable.getColumns().get(1) ));
```

Comment: Thank you. I have seen the same solution posted in other SOF posts with similar queries. While it may be useful, it's too complex in terms of processing that list of column names recorded as RelationalPa and then converting to string to compare (which not sure how it could be done, working with limited knowledge of Java here :) ).

Comment: Also, it is typically not used and not necessary. Normally, you design your dbase such that you do not have that issue.