# How to read different columns in rows in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, database, anylogic

I would like to ask you for advice. While working on my diploma thesis in AnyLogic (based on java) I got stuck with a problem. I have an Excel table imported to AnyLogic as a database and the table looks like this:

[image: Table format]

I need to read all columns called "route" row by row and load them to a collection as an array list.

I think the problem is that the "route" column isn't at the beginning and also I want the program to read more than one column. In addition, each row has a different number of "route" columns that the program is supposed to read.

I tried to create a function, but I struggle with the writing of the function body. I was able to read only one column ("route1") so far.

```
selectFrom(test_data)
    .where(test_data.id.eq(ID))
    .list(test_data.route1)
);
```

Can anyone help me please? Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question should get you most of the way there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122438/. It's close to a duplicate but I won't flag this one as a duplicate of that yet.

Comment: I fixed your image link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many records you have, it might actually be simpler to create a type of agent that maps to a record using [this method](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/agent-type.html) and selecting `Use database table` option.

Then you can create a population of that type of agent and point it to your database table. At model start up it will load the records, create an agent per record and then you can operate on them directly without having to write a database query.